# How to correctly write this norm symbol?

Tags: math-mode

I would like to write a norm symbol of not two double vertical lines but rather two triple vertical lines. Currently I am doing it as `\|| \cdot \||` instead of `\| \cdot \|`, but I have two issues with this typing: (1) it does not adjust the size of the vertical lines if, for some reason, the object replacing `\cdot` is too big, and (2) it does not look good; the space between each line is different.

How can I solve this?

---

Excuse me, but I didn't know how to correcctly tag this question.

Comment: While this might be a duplicate: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @Lukin254: You may notice that I've restored the original text to your question. We would like to keep it so that people who come here (e.g. from Google) are able to see what you asked and follow the link to the correct answer. Again, Welcome to TeX.SX!